# How to make ImageView be left of a TextView, when Textview is HorizontalCentered

Tags: android, text, textview, center, gravity

I have a XML file with RelativeLayout, I also have Textview which has Gravity Center. In code I would like to get X coordinate of this Textview, where the TextView begins (length of TextView is not constant, it can change). I need a ImageView to be next to the TextView.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView" /> `

    countryText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    countryText.getLeft()

getLeft() return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add android:layout_centerInParent="true" to textview and add android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView6" to imageview

Answer (score 0):

Simply get rid of the ImageView and add a **compound drawable** to the left of your TextView.
This is also more efficient, because it helps flattening your layout hierarchy.

I.e.:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TextView"
/>
```

Official [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableLeft)